# Pandas: Groupby return error after PD cuts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of `Age` and `Marital_Status`. The `age` is `int` and `Marital_Status` is `string` with 8 unique string eg: Married, Single etc.

After dividing into age group of interval 10

`df['age_group'] = pd.cut(df.Age,bins=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90])`

I had group the marital status by age group

`df.groupby(['age_group'])['Marital_Status'].value_counts().`

With error as below return

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (9,) (7,)`

When i tried with smaller number of age_group where the shape <= (7,) the `groupby` works fine. eg

`df['age_group'] = pd.cut(df.Age,bins=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80])`

I presume that the first shape `(x,)` must be smaller than second shape `(y,)`. Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: Is possible in `df['age_group']` some missing values? How working `df.dropna('age_group').groupby(['age_group'])['Marital_Status'].value_counts()` ?

Comment: Hi Thanks, sorry that my question is not clear. I have gotten it to work by reducing the number of age_group from 9 to 7 intervals. I am just trying to understand why does having bigger number of  interval causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem (maybe bug?) in [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), default parameter is `observed=False`, but you need working only with existing categoricals:

> observed bool, default False

> This only applies if any of the groupers are Categoricals. If True: only show observed values for categorical groupers. If False: show all values for categorical groupers.

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Marital_Status':['stat1'] * 50,
                   'Age': range(50)})

df['age_group'] = pd.cut(df.Age,bins=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80])
# print (df)
    
print (df.groupby(['age_group'], observed=True)['Marital_Status'].value_counts())
age_group  Marital_Status
(10, 20]   stat1             10
(20, 30]   stat1             10
(30, 40]   stat1             10
(40, 50]   stat1              9
Name: Marital_Status, dtype: int64
```

In alternative solution better is possible check difference:

```
print (df.groupby(['age_group', 'Marital_Status']).size())
age_group  Marital_Status
(10, 20]   stat1             10
(20, 30]   stat1             10
(30, 40]   stat1             10
(40, 50]   stat1              9
(50, 60]   stat1              0
(60, 70]   stat1              0
(70, 80]   stat1              0
dtype: int64

print (df.groupby(['age_group', 'Marital_Status'], observed=True).size())
age_group  Marital_Status
(10, 20]   stat1             10
(20, 30]   stat1             10
(30, 40]   stat1             10
(40, 50]   stat1              9
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! now i got it that the problem lies with value that doesnt fall under a category. learnt something new. thanks again